# Visual C++ methods in vfptr in reverse order

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, overloading

Is there a way to control the order of some classes methods in the vfptr? It seems that Visual C++ 2010 at least puts the method pointers in the declaration order, except for overloaded methods. Below is sample code:

```
enum ENUM {
};

class CLASS {
    virtual void foo1() { };
    virtual CLASS& __cdecl operator<<(const ENUM x) { return *this; };
    virtual void foo2() { };
    virtual CLASS& __cdecl operator<<(const char* x) { return *this; };
    virtual CLASS& __cdecl operator<<(int x) { return *this; };
    virtual void foo3() { };
    virtual void foo1(int x) { };
};

int main() {
    CLASS c;
    return 0;
}
```

The above code generates following vfptr:

```
[0] 0x00e21091 CLASS::foo1(int) *
[1] 0x00e2100a CLASS::foo1(void)    *
[2] 0x00e211ae CLASS::operator<<(int)   *
[3] 0x00e21050 CLASS::operator<<(char const *)  *
[4] 0x00e211db CLASS::operator<<(enum ENUM) *
[5] 0x00e2106e CLASS::foo2(void)    *
[6] 0x00e21172 CLASS::foo3(void)    *
```

So the overloaded methods get grouped to first such declaration and then reversed. Having them grouped together isn't a problem, since I can group them in the header file easily. However the reverse order is a problem as different compilers apparently won't do that which means they will call wrong methods. This is related to passing object pointers between application and a DLL.

First I hoped MSVC has a preferred order for overloaded methods, so I tried to declare the methods in the order MSVC had them in the vfptr, but then it simply reversed them again, here's the code and result of that:

```
class CLASS {
    virtual void foo1(int x) { };
    virtual void foo1() { };
    virtual CLASS& operator<<(int x) { return *this; };
    virtual CLASS& operator<<(const char* x) { return *this; };
    virtual CLASS& operator<<(const ENUM x) { return *this; };
    virtual void foo2() { };
    virtual void foo3() { };
};
```

result:

```
[0] 0x0113100a CLASS::foo1(void)    *
[1] 0x01131091 CLASS::foo1(int) *
[2] 0x011311db CLASS::operator<<(enum ENUM) *
[3] 0x01131050 CLASS::operator<<(char const *)  *
[4] 0x011311ae CLASS::operator<<(int)   *
[5] 0x0113106e CLASS::foo2(void)    *
[6] 0x01131172 CLASS::foo3(void)    *
```

I'd like to use method overloading, there's at least one hack I could use (know the order MSVC will use, create new header with that order to be used only by the DLLs), but I'd rather get it to work properly in the first place. Or is it at all possible?

Comment: If I were you, I would give up trying to pass C++ classes between the application and DLLs, unless they were all compiled with the same version of the same compiler. I would create a C API instead. If you can't change the DLL, you can make your own vtable as a struct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use C++ interfaces between modules even with different compilers but you have just bumped into an edge case. Here is why do interfaces work across different compilers: Usable C++ compilers must produce code that works with COM interfaces. A COM object looks quite like a C++ object with a single vtable whose pointer is at offset zero of the object. The problem is that COM doesn't define any rules for overloaded methods as far as I know but as long as you don't want to exploit method overloading and maybe some other exotic language features then you can trust method order (because of the COM compatibility).

Even if you don't use C++ interfaces between modules your interface between modules should be reasonably simple. I was never in burning need of method overloads in an interface between modules. Even if you needed an overload you can give the methods separate names just like in languages where you don't have overloading at all. Passing primitive types and simple data structures between modules is also wise, if you pass only primitive types then it is very easy to compile modules with different configs (like one in Debug and the others in Release) to speed up debugging iterations.

Comment: So your take is that because COM doesn't use overloading thus other compilers for Windows haven't bothered to "copy" MS way of overloading methods? Which means I'm out of luck and will either have to drop overloading or use the hack I mentioned?

Comment: As for "giving the methods separate names", you mean instead of `void foo1(); void foo1(int x);` I could use `void foo1_void(); void foo1_int(int x);`? That would be one way of working around this issue, but with that approach I would have to call separate methods based on the argument type, instead of the "stream" approach that cout, cin and others use with `operator<<`.

Comment: I wouldn't rely on things like overloading between compilers. But, anyway, if you are crossing module borders you have to be aware of many other (and even bigger) things too like memory management of passed objects... Still in my opinion using a C++ interface as an inter-module interface is a very good thing. When I use DLLs for example as plugins then I usually export just one function from the modules (using platform dependent ugly exporting) and this single exported function then returns a C++ interface. In C I usually returned a pointer to a struct that contained function ptrs...

Comment: The stream approach sucks anyway in my opinion but that is a different story... I think overloading comes handy sometimes (for exmaple when you have a method that can process ints, floats, ... But in case of interface methods I wouldn't try to trick myself with overloads. Period. You can check out other windows compilers whether they copy the Visual C++ style ordering, I don't know...

Comment: I do pretty much the same. I have a function within the DLL to create an object within the DLL and return a pointer that is cast to the interface class. So far this is working nicely (due to COM compatibility). So the only things I pass are primitive types, I do all memory release in same module where it was allocated, etc. This was the first time I tried to use overloaded methods and after some debugging realized why, now all I need to know is there something that can be done or not? If you _know_ it can't be done, can you edit your answer to include that and I'll accept it.

Comment: Btw, I tested having two different header files, "mangling" the second one to have reverse order for the overloaded methods and used that with GCC, it works. I just hoped I didn't have to use a hack.

Comment: I don't know, maybe overloading can be done, I just don't know about the existence of any evidence and many years ago I remember that I had a lot of trouble because of this vtbl-overloading issue but I don't exactly remember why because it was almost 10 years ago. This is why do I knew what I described in my answer. BTW, are you sure that the order of overloads is reverse, it could be ordering by something else, for example method signature generated by the compiler... You can easily test it, just swap two methods and if the order remain the same then its not reverse order but something else.

Comment: I tested it in my question, the first code vs the second one. I'll just use the hack, as it seems to work reliably. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. Nice, it is some plus info for me too.