# Why are overridden pure virtual functions placed differently by MSVC and GCC in vtable?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, disassembly

First, [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```cpp
#include <cstdio>

class Base {
public:
    virtual void Print(int x) = 0;
    virtual void Print(double x) = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    void Print(int x) override { printf("%d\n", x); }
    void Print(double x) override { printf("%lf\n", x); }
};

int main(void) {
    class Derived obj;
    obj.Print(2);
    obj.Print(3.141);
}
```

In the above C++ code, Base class has two pure virtual functions of same function
name but different argument type -- **First** one prints integer and **Second**
one prints double. It is important to have same virtual method names because if
the method names are same then MSVC and GCC produces same effect in result binary.

In disassembly ([IDA](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/)):

- GCC 10.2.0: `g++.exe -Wall -pedantic test.cpp`

```
.rdata:A0 ; `typeinfo name for'Base
.rdata:A0 _ZTS4Base       db '4Base',0            ; type descriptor name
.rdata:A6                 align 10h
.rdata:B0                 public _ZTS7Derived
.rdata:B0 ; `typeinfo name for'Derived
.rdata:B0 _ZTS7Derived    db '7Derived',0         ; type descriptor name
.rdata:B9                 align 20h
.rdata:C0                 public _ZTV7Derived
.rdata:C0 ; `vtable for'Derived
.rdata:C0 _ZTV7Derived    dq 0                    ; offset to this
.rdata:C8                 dq offset _ZTI7Derived  ; `typeinfo for'Derived
.rdata:D0 off_4098D0      dq offset _ZN7Derived5PrintEi ; Derived::Print(int)
.rdata:D8                 dq offset _ZN7Derived5PrintEd ; Derived::Print(double)
```

- MSVC 19.26.28806: `cl.exe /Zi test.cpp`

```
.rdata:20                  dq offset ??_R4Base@@6B@              ; const Base::`RTTI Complete Object Locator'
.rdata:28 ??_7Base@@6B@    dq offset j__purecall
.rdata:30                  dq offset j__purecall
.rdata:38                  align 20h
.rdata:40                  dq offset ??_R4Derived@@6B@           ; const Derived::`RTTI Complete Object Locator'
.rdata:48 ??_7Derived@@6B@ dq offset j_?Print@Derived@@UEAAXN@Z  ; Derived::Print(double)
.rdata:50                  dq offset j_?Print@Derived@@UEAAXH@Z  ; Derived::Print(int)
```

In the Derived vtable, the `Derived::Print(int)` and `Derived::Print(double)`
are in opposite order between GCC and MVSC produced binaries. So, why is the
order of pure virtual methods different in the vtable in the binary produced by
GCC and MSVC? Also why does this happen only if the methods are overridden?

Comment: How the vtable is implemented is a compiler detail, and not specified by the C++ standard.  So compiler developers are free to come up with different solutions.  (Similar to name mangling.  Different compilers, different mangling.)

Comment: Searching did not turn up true duplicates (since this question is "why" and the ones I found asked variations on "how"), but the information you are looking for is possibly in [Inversion of generated vtable functions order for functions with the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61542063) and [Visual C++ methods in vfptr in reverse order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22059092/).

Comment: I didn't get the answer of my 2nd question.